# ie complicated subdomain cookie problem

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, header

all my cookies work great on subdomain, but if subdomain has "_" in it, then cookie dont get read at all and dont get right at all eaither. following are my tested result, which will self explain

```
justlife.demo.com        *** works fine ***
just-life.demo.com       *** works fine ***
just-.demo.com           *** works fine ***

just_.demo.com           *** DONT works fine ***
just_life.demo.com       *** DONT works fine ***
```

domain that dont work, the cookies for them shows completely emtpy and you cant write or read from that sub-domains..

this problem is only in IE.

firefox and chrome works fine, they dont have this error.

any solutions? these subdomains are usernames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE has problems with underscores in sub domain namens. See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies).

From there:

> MSIE 7, on a domain with an underscore, silently drops all cookies for that host and refuses to accept new ones.
>
> only solution is to use RFC-compliant domains (I've replaced all the "_"s with "-"s and set up a RewriteRule so that traffic is redirected to the compliant domains).

I'm afraid you are going to have to drop the underscore domains, or work around your cookie problem.

Comment: thank you... do you know how can i find sub-domain in url and re-write the rule, its best if i get subdomians and put that in end or url with &username=subdomain.. can you help me on this.

Comment: That's possible to do. Open a new question and add `mod_rewrite` as a tag, somebody will be able to help along.