# Devise gem not working for IE8 in staging (but works for Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, rubygems, devise

We use devise 1.0.6 (Ruby 1.9.2 / Rails 2.3.8) for authentication.

For some reason on staging, user authentication seems to be not working in IE8 because, when registered users log in, they did not get redirected to their own desk page (desk_user_url, see below).  They got redirected to the landing (home) page instead.

=====

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:support]
  protect_from_forgery :except => :community

  def landing
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to desk_user_url
      return
    end
  end
```

======

However, it works just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Is this a problem with devise or is it something else?

Thanks.

Comment: In staging? What's the domain like? Is it a subdomain with underscores by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Internet Explorer ignores cookies on some domains (cannot read or set cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies)

Comment: It seems like there was some sort of conflict in the cookie (by IE8) since I was testing both staging and production.  Thanks for the pointer.