# Rails 3, protect_from_forgery and IE8 problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, protect-from-forgery

I have a rails app that all works fine for me in all browsers (Safari, Firefox, IE6, 7, 8 etc)

I have a new user who has a fairly locked down version of IE8 and as soon as they try to access the app, before they even get to the login page, they get a Windows Authentication prompt appear. If they try to enter the login details they have been provided it fails. I'm not really worried about it failing, as the authentication prompt shouldn't be appearing.

As soon as I remove protect_from_forgery from the ApplicationController they can access the system fine.

I've tried suggesting allowing cookies etc, but they are still getting the problem. Has anyone got any suggestions as to other things we could look

Just to add to this.  The site uses a basecamp style subdomain system.  Not certain if that's an issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Rails are you using? Which authentication framework are you using?

I had the same behavior with Rails 3.0.3 and some earlier version of Devise. The issue I had was that in some circumstances IE8 decides to send 'Accept-Type: */*' in the HTTP header instead of a long line of supported formats. Somewhere within Rails/Devise something slipped and a HTTP authentication status was sent back.

I solved my problem by upgrading to Rails 3.0.5 and Devise 1.2.rc2.

Comment: I'm running Rails 3.0.5 and Devise 1.1.9

Comment: Try do look at the HTTP request headers for the requests that prompt for authentication and see if it may be the same issue. I used Fiddler for inspecting the request headers.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  The bit I'm really struggling with it's fine for most people using IE8.  It's just this one particular client.

Comment: I've upgrade to Devise 1.2.1 and that seems to have resolved the issue.  Now I need to fix mm-devise to work with Devise 1.2.1 :)

Comment: Great. I did spend quite a bit of time and didn't qui

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else still has problems with this, I am using Rails 3.0.9 and Devise 1.2.1 and was still having this problem. My problem was that IE won't set cookies for subdomains with an underscore in them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies) for the details. So I changed my subdomains to use dashes and it works now.