# Cookie via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to set a cookie via AJAX directly with PHP. The code below sets the cookie just fine in Firefox, Opera and Safari, but not in Chrome and IE8.

```
`setcookie( "user" , $_REQUEST[ 'login' ] , time() + 60 * 60 * 60 , "/graduate/" , "localhost" );`
```

Am I missing something, or is the only way to do it is through JavaScript?

P.S. Using JavaScript the cookie is set in all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i'm guessing youre doing this on a localhost? If so, its because google chrome has an issue with localhost sites and using the IP Address to set the cookies instead, more here: http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/iow88FsnNhQ

For internet Explorer, here is an excerpt from php site that should solve your problem:
"Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 9 (IE8 and IE9) are still not accepting cookies from localhost.

The simplest way around this is adding an entry to your hosts file e.g. 127.0.0.1 www.mytestsite.com"

Here is the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Another issue is that some browsers dont work well unless you specify all the parameters of setcookie, try that too

Some other links that may be of help:
[Internet Explorer ignores cookies on some domains (cannot read or set cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies)

Comment: It solved Chrome's problem, but not IE's. +1 for half answer.

Comment: Added the IE part buddy, hope it helps

Comment: Arent you supposed to +1 more for the other half of the answer? :D lol