# ie doesn't save cookies on localhost

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-9

I got a problem here. My IE9 does not accept cookies. Security levels and stuff are ok. Everything says cookies should be accepted but they are not!

```
$cookie = 'abc';
setcookie('id', $cookie, time() + 8640000);
```

This works in all other browsers except my beloved one ;(

Answer (score 2):

try to set cookie like so this may work:

```
var now = new Date();
        var time = now.getTime();
        time += 3600 * 1000;
        now.setTime(time);
document.cookie =
                'cookiename=cookievalue' +
                '; expires=' + now.toGMTString() +
                '; path=/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here... Try to reset IE settings and DON'T use "Disable cookies" from developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Check solution here - [Internet Explorer ignores cookies on some domains (cannot read or set cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies) - unacceptable domain name, it helped me. Or here - http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesie.html - IE cookies settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use your internal IP address

Start Menu -> Type CMD -> type in IPConfig /ALL

Look for IPv4 Address:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.12(Preferred)
```

In the browser address bar simply replace `localhost` for the IP address
So that `localhost/mywebsite/` becomes `192.168.0.12/mywebsite/`

IE will then work as normal with cookies