# Rails 3.2, Devise 2.2.3 & IE8 login issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer-8, devise

I've read through a ton of seemingly similar issues on SO and blogs about setting cookies to work across domains, but my issue is more specific than that.  In general, my session_store for cookies works like a charm in dev and prod, across browsers and across sub-domains with the single exception of IE8, which won't let me login (it just redirects me back to the landing page again), and presumably the issue is that it won't issue a cookie.

My session_store.rb initializer is:

```
  Xavy2::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => 'sitesession', domain: ".site.com"
```

Here is the output from one IE8 login attept

```
2013-08-19T15:50:13.352878+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 154.51.130.161 at 2013-08-19 15:50:13 +0000
2013-08-19T15:49:03.398016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=www.xavy.com fwd="84.207.252.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1263ms status=302 bytes=86
2013-08-19T15:50:18.350332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=www.xavy.com fwd="154.51.130.161" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5033ms status=200 bytes=8737
2013-08-19T15:50:29.746857+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 154.51.130.161 at 2013-08-19 15:50:29 +0000
2013-08-19T15:50:30.282263+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=www.xavy.com fwd="154.51.130.161" dyno=web.1 connect=14ms service=542ms status=302 bytes=86
2013-08-19T15:50:30.409250+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 154.51.130.161 at 2013-08-19 15:50:30 +0000
2013-08-19T15:50:30.679531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=www.xavy.com fwd="154.51.130.161" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=276ms status=200 bytes=9291
2 service=6ms status=200 bytes=84056
```

I'm not sure if that's relevant or what else someone would need to see to help me debug or resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is there an underscore in the domain?  if so that's probably the issue: [Internet Explorer ignores cookies on some domains (cannot read or set cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies)