# Session not working on localhost using IE 9 and virtual host

Tags: internet-explorer, session, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

Recently I ran into a very weird problem and couldn't find the solution after looking through every possible forum and other internet resources.

The situation was the following:

I was developing a PHP website using WAMP. I set up a virtual host called **rienn_laravel** so I can access the site on localhost by the address

```
http://rienn_laravel/
```

The site was working perfectly in the latest Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 9 I was unable to use Sessions. I couldn't login, or access the error/notice messages which I put in session.

I used the following setup.

In httpd-vhosts.conf I had the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/project"
    ServerName rienn_laravel

    <Directory "C:/path/to/project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my hosts file I added the following row:

```
127.0.0.1       rienn_laravel
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer ignores cookies on some domains (cannot read or set cookies)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This describes why IE correctly has an issue with your domain name.

**What are the valid characters for a domain name and how long can it be ?**

When choosing the name for your domain, always remember that: - you *can't* use stressed vowels (such as à, é, ò, etc.); - you *can't* use symbols (such as ' + . , | ! " £ $ % & / ( ) = ? ^ * ç ° § ; : _ > ] [ @ ); - the name's length must range between 3 and 63 characters (excluding the extension); - the name can neither start nor end with the character "-", although the character "-" is allowed inside the name. So, to name your domain you can use any letter, numbers between 0 and 9, and the symbol "-". .

Length may vary, from 3 to 63 types.

I have no idea why the other browsers work with an underscore in the domain name but basically `_` is not a valid character.

You are best sticking to something like `rienn-laravel.dev` or `rienn-laravel.localhost` but avoiding using a real tld like .com etc as using one of those would mean you could not access the real site when you have a host file entry pointing that to 127.0.0.1

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112/en-us and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Comment: salute for finding that out... I almost lost it while looking for it!!

Answer (score 1):

This unusual problem was caused by the **underscore** sign in the virtual host's name.

After I changed the virtual host name to a name without an underscore, everything was working fine. I tried **rienn**, **laravel.rienn**, **laravel.rienn.dev**. All variation worked perfectly in IE 9 too.

Unfortunately I have no idea why an underscore caused such problem in IE 9, if you know please let me and others know.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this, it is the underscore in the domain name. I ran into the same problem some time ago, and solved it by replacing all '_' with '.' ..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10896648)

Comment: Thank you Cindy, you're right. I was not so familiar with the rules.