# Why are session values 'null', when I use an underscore "_" in my domain name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am using ASP.NET MVC4, .NET Framework 4.5 and IIS8. My application can be invoked via the url `http://vm_windows8`. On first request, the following code snipped will be executed:

```
Session["Value"] = "MyStoredValue";
```

On a later request the value will be extracted from the session:

```
if(Session["Value"] == null)
    throw new Exception("Session 'Value' is null.");

// ... code ...
```

Every time, the `Session["Value"]` is null. But when I remove the underscore from the url `http://vmwindows8` the session is not null all works as expected.

Does anyone know the issue / solution using underscores "_" in the url in combination with sessions?

Comment: Are you sure that session has been started before your code?

Comment: Are you using IE? I think it fails to write cookies when there's a underscore.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies

Comment: @khellang: thank you, you are right. Should I delete this question because of possible duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions and cookies are blocked by the browser if you make use of special characters

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316112